# Resize of Content of Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

I have modal bootstrap that I have some element in content of this modal but when size of content is bigger than modal, the modal does not resize it and I get scroll to navigate whole element but I want that bootstrap modal resize this content in every screen. my Content is below:

[image]

***And bottom with scroll to navigate all element***

[image]

my modal:

```
 <div id="seatModal" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sakuModal" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="row" title="-_-_-">
                            <div class="col-md-12 overflow-auto SeatPanelBody" title="-_-_-">
                                  <div class="SeatPanelSeats" style="text-align:center;" title="-_-_-">
                                 <div class="seatRow" title="-_-_-">
                                  <div class="seatRowHeader">1</div><span class="seatSold" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" id="76877" t="2" title="سانس : 19:00<br/>جایگاه : میلاد&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ردیف : 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;صندلی : 1<br/>فروخته شده">1</span>
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

How to resize of content of modal to fit to modal width without scroll to navigate all content?

Comment: Could you share your CSS also?Stackblitz example would be the best

Comment: you can use @media quires to set the width and height based on the screen size. you can add width to **modal-lg**  class by using media quires.  check the  below link how to use media quires [check](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery_breakpoints)